# How to transform an old branch into a tag on GitHub

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch, git-tag

My first actually serious project on GitHub has some time ago underwent a complete change of stack - from Python to NodeJS. However, at the time being a complete git noob I created a branch with all the Python code and then deleted everything on the master branch and started implementing the system in NodeJS.

Now I'm still a git noob but I realised I should have used a tag instead of a branch. So I have this `old_python` branch hanging there and it annoys me.

How can I get rid of that branch but still be able to quickly have a look at the Python code which would be a tag? I dont plan on commiting anything to the Python codebase so the branch seems unnecessary.

Or, perhaps, I am completely misunderstanding what tags are for and should leave it/do something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the tag

```
git tag <tagname> origin/old_python
```

Delete the branch (if you have a local branch)

```
git branch -d old_python
```

Push the tag

```
git push --tags origin
```

Delete the remote branch

```
git push origin :old_python
```

Comment: The #1 comes back with `fatal: Failed to resolve 'old_python' as a valid ref.` I suppose that means I have to add that branch locally somehow?

Comment: I presumed you had a local branch named `old_python`. Run `git branch -a` to see a list of your branches. You may have one called `origin/old_python`. If you do, use that instead for the first step and skip the second step.

Comment: Yes sorry its remotes all the way down. Worked like a charm, thanks!